# How to Prevent Android FragmentStatePagerAdapter from Creating Neighboring Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am creating an Android app, and I have linked a`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to a `TabBar` inside one of my `Activities` to allow users to slide from `Fragment` to `Fragment`. Each `Fragment` in this `Activity` is populated by a REST call, and if it fails, a `Dialog` will pop-up saying you should try and refresh your information (only the first time you view the `Fragment`). The problem I am having is that since `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` creates the neighboring `Fragments` to the `Fragment` you are currently on, it is creating the `Dialog`(s) of said `Fragments` prematurely (For example if you are on `Fragment` 3, and `Fragment` 4 prompts a `Dialog`, it will show on `Fragment 3` instead of `Fragment 4`). Is there a way to turn off the creation of neighboring `Fragments` using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the number of neighboring fragments that area created by calling `setOffscreenPageLimit`, but the minimum is 1.

Instead of creating your Dialogs in the fragments' `onCreateView`, I would do it [setUserVisibleHint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)) instead. That way the dialog is only created when you're certain that the user is on the page.

Answer (score 0):

No i think you can't , Though there is a property for view pager

```
  viewpager.setOffscreenLimit(0) //defaults to 1
```

but you can try some other solutions

1. show Dialog in onResume();
2. make an interface in Acitvity and fire up to it's implementation in Fragment

   tab.setOntabselected{

   Pageselected(pagenumber)

}